# Intermittent 401 error from Artifactory when deploying files

Tags: maven, artifactory

During our intraday builds, we intermittently (perhaps twice a day) get a '401 Unauthorized' error when maven performs the 'deploy' step of the build. This error is seen on both the maven console and in the Artifactory requests.log. The time of day isn't consistent, nor is it tied to a snapshot/release repository. I've checked and doublechecked all security settings and urls, and since this error is intermittent, I'm confident the issue lies with Artifactory.

I also get this intermittently with a 'mvn deploy:deploy-file'. Today it failed on 1 upload out of approx 300.

I've raised a jira with Artifactory but it's not been picked up yet: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14982

I should add that we didn't encounter this issue when using Archiva as our repository. It's happened regularly since I migrated to Artifactory

Comment: Does that happen on the same build? Is the same build failing and later on succeeding or there are different builds that some are failing and some are working.

Comment: Intermittently on any build. All builds work successfully 95% of the time

Comment: have you solved this issue? i've same problem, i'm going crazy!!!

Comment: Afraid not. I had to disable authentication on artifactory to get reliable builds:/ Hardly an ideal workaround

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the pom.xml example, the reason it is failing is that the [deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) goal is missing the `repositoryId` property.
This property should include the repository id for the repository you use for deployment, for example:

```
<repositoryId>internal-snapshot-local</repositoryId>
```

The plugin will use this id for getting the deployer credentials from the Maven settings.xml file.

Comment: That isn't necessary when I run it locally. It picks up the repositoryId from the distributionManagement element

Comment: I don't think the deploy-file goal does that. It seems that only the deploy goal is using the distributionManagement

Comment: Regardless of how it works, the setting on the repository to allow anonymous deployments changes whether or not it works. This isn't an actual pom file in my project, it's just a demo of how to trigger the issue

Comment: The issue that this demo pom shows is that Maven will not authenticate in certain configurations. It has nothing to do with Artifactory.

Comment: Added the repositoryId. Here is the error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.
2:deploy (default-deploy) on project rtfact-14982: Failed to deploy artifacts: C
ould not transfer artifact com.artifactory:rtfact-14982:jar:1.0-20170929.155822-
2 from/to internal-snapshot-local (http://jfrog:8081/artifactory/internal-snapsh
ot/): Failed to transfer file: http://jfrog:8081/artifactory/internal-snapshot/c
om/artifactory/rtfact-14982/1.0-SNAPSHOT/rtfact-14982-1.0-20170929.155822-2.jar.
 Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]

Comment: I created a project based on this example pom, added the repositoryId, verified that it is present in my settings.xml and it works fine. I'm able to deploy to a repository using a user with deploy permissions. I don't think this is related to your bigger issue of intermittent deployment failures.

Comment: Ok, I'll drop the example from the post and just hope someone picks up the Jira in JFrog